# Comparing data using hash sets

Tags: java, equals, hashset, hashcode

I’m working on creating a module to compare two datasets A and B. They both have different number of columns.

For a row in A to equal a row in B, I need to compare 3 columns in A to two columns in B. Lets call them `A1-3` and `B1-2`. The criteria is :

1: `A1 == B1`

2: `A2 == B2 OR A3 == B2`

I am trying to create a solution using `HashSet`s, and overriding hash code and equals method. Well the `OR` criteria is really giving me a headache.

I was able to create a solution with only comparing `A1==A2` and `B1==B2`. In that case, I used hash and equals with the two columns. But how do I account for the `OR` in hashcode? Should I just hash the first columns? And let the equals decide the equality?

Is my approach wrong here? Or anyone have a better way to do this? Trying to keep `O(n)` worst case.

Edit: I am using the set’s addAll and retainAll methods to find the matches

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple code in Java in the equal method that do as you say, but, as Mathematician, I can answer you cannot solve using only a hash for each row,  because the "OR" that you have there leads to a non-transitive relation:

For example, you may have 3 rows, A=(0,1,1), B=(2,1,0) and C=(3,0,0), so that

- A is equal to B (with your criteria)
- B is equal to C (with your criteria)
- A is NOT equal to C (with your criteria)

So, hash(A)=hash(B) and hash(B)=hash(C) but ¿hash(A)!=hash(C)?

so, there is no way that you can traslate this into a single hash compare.